# UITextView last line is not shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I got an UITextView with content:
A
A
A

[image]

and here it is, as I see there are lots of spacing below the last line, so I reduce the TextView height by few pixels.

[image]

and the last 'A' disappear, and there is obviously lots of spacing for the letter 'A', any idea?

Comment: Are there any bottom margins to the text view? Maybe it seems like the letter would fit, but with margins and all there just isn't enough space for it?

Comment: Ah, another good explanation of the behavior. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think reason is height of textview not enough for inset of textview and lint padding. Try:

```
    self.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```

Comment: This post deserves more visibility

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the content size of UITextView is not correct.
I faced the same issue when I disable edit or select.
And the log tells the width of content size was 0, and the height was not correct as well.
Try:

```
textView.contentSize = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size)
```

That works for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the space is too small to draw every possible character available in Unicode and the font (esp. those with descender) so the layout machinery does not layout the whole line, even there would be enough space for the A. If they do not so, changing of the text could potentially hide and unhide the last line, what would be puzzling.

If you are really sure that there is no such problem, you could embed the text view in a superview, clipping the text view.